# VS Code CPP Extension hogs up the CPU constantly / Infinite loop in the Intellisense process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm working with vs code and it's cpp extension under Ubuntu 18.04.
However after starting the app one CPU is under full load, although I'm not doing anything. The CPU fan is driving me crazy!

The problem is well documented, but without any working solution
[VS Code CPP Extension hogs up the CPU almost constantly in the latest version #2742](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2742) and
[Infinite loop in the Intellisense process #1294](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1294)

Did anyone have similar problems? Is there any alternative to Microsofts c++ extension?

I already tried "C/C++ Runner" by franneck94 but the problem seems to remain there as well as it depends on microsofts c++ extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already seem to have found the answer. vscode is only excluding certain build directories like

```
**/build
```

In my case, I had a bazel build project (mediapipe) and the cpp indexer was probably following the bazel symlinks into the bazel cache rabbit hole.

Anyway, after adding `**/bazel*` to the files / folders to exclude the CPU stopped running forever!

This can be done under File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> C/C++ Runner -> C_Cpp_Runner: ExcludeSearch -> Add "**/bazel*"

Comment: Since I'm not an advanced user, I just disabled extensions one by one - Pylance was the culprit, and 'code' cpu usage is back down to immaterial #.

Comment: I have uninstall all of my extension, it still shows hogging.